# Connect PostgreSQL database with password to pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to connect a PostgreSQL database to pgAdmin.

The only information I have about the database are:

- postgres://candidate.company.org/company
- Username: banana
- Password: aaabbbccc

On pgAdmin I do:

1) Click on `Add new server`

2) Fill the info as in photo [image: o]

3) Press `save`

**BUT** I get:

> > Unable to connect to server:
> >
> > could not translate host name "postgres://candidate.company.org/company" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: try to provide candiate.company.org alone in host name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like someone gave you a JDBC url.  The hostname is just candidate.company.org.  The database is company.